# how to create a counting column for a particular item

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have the following schema (mysql)

```
create table test(
  userid int(11) not null,
  item varchar(15),
  bookid int(11));

insert into test values ('1','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('2','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('2','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('2','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('3','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('3','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('2','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('2','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('2','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('1','journal',NULL);
insert into test values ('3','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('3','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('3','book',NULL);
insert into test values ('3','book',NULL);
```

whenever there is a book, I'm trying assign an auto increment beginning with 1 in the bookid column. For each user, the numbering begins again from 1. I know a way this can be done by creating a separate table. Is there a way I can avoid that and accomplish that using some sort of update query in this very table and update the column bookid? I am trying to get output similar to the following:

```
userid,item,bookid
'1','journal',NULL
'1','journal',NULL
'1','book',1
'2','book',1
'2','journal',NULL
'1','book',2
'2','journal',NULL
'3','book',1
'1','book',3
'1','journal',NULL
'3','journal',NULL
'1','journal',NULL
'2','journal',NULL
'2','book',2
'2','journal',NULL
'1','journal',NULL
'3','book',2
'3','book',3
'3','book',4
'3','book',5
```

I appreciate if someone could guide me on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea...

```
  drop table if exists test;

  create table test
  (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,userid int not null
  ,item varchar(15) NOT NULL
  );

  insert into test (userid,item) values 
   (1,'journal')
  ,(1,'journal')
  ,(1,'book')
  ,(2,'book')
  ,(2,'journal')
  ,(1,'book')
  ,(2,'journal')
  ,(3,'book')
  ,(1,'book')
  ,(1,'journal')
  ,(3,'journal')
  ,(1,'journal')
  ,(2,'journal')
  ,(2,'book')
  ,(2,'journal')
  ,(1,'journal')
  ,(3,'book')
  ,(3,'book')
  ,(3,'book')
  ,(3,'book');

  SELECT x.*
       , COUNT(*) rank 
    FROM test x 
    JOIN test y 
      ON y.userid = x.userid 
     AND y.item = x.item 
     AND y.id <= x.id 
   GROUP 
      BY id 
   ORDER 
      BY userid
       , item
       , rank;
  +----+--------+---------+------+
  | id | userid | item    | rank |
  +----+--------+---------+------+
  |  3 |      1 | book    |    1 |
  |  6 |      1 | book    |    2 |
  |  9 |      1 | book    |    3 |
  |  1 |      1 | journal |    1 |
  |  2 |      1 | journal |    2 |
  | 10 |      1 | journal |    3 |
  | 12 |      1 | journal |    4 |
  | 16 |      1 | journal |    5 |
  |  4 |      2 | book    |    1 |
  | 14 |      2 | book    |    2 |
  |  5 |      2 | journal |    1 |
  |  7 |      2 | journal |    2 |
  | 13 |      2 | journal |    3 |
  | 15 |      2 | journal |    4 |
  |  8 |      3 | book    |    1 |
  | 17 |      3 | book    |    2 |
  | 18 |      3 | book    |    3 |
  | 19 |      3 | book    |    4 |
  | 20 |      3 | book    |    5 |
  | 11 |      3 | journal |    1 |
  +----+--------+---------+------+
```

Note that MyISAM actually lets you use a composite PK in which part of that composite is an auto-incrementing id, but InnoDB prohinits this.

On larger datasets a query along these lines will likely be far more efficient...

```
SELECT id
     , userid
     , item
     , IF(@userid=userid,IF(@item=item,@i:=@i+1,@i:=1),@i:=1) rank
     , @userid := userid
     , @item := item 
  FROM test
     , (SELECT @userid = NULL,@item:='',@i:=1) vars
 ORDER 
    BY userid,item,id;
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to do this on 15 million records with multiple columns? I might have lock table problems. I've been looking for a solution that might update on the same table (if that's less expensive. )